# JSON - how to get a "path" to object

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

In my React project I have a nested JSON and I want to get a key to the object as a string:

Assuming I have a JSON of

```
{
  "section_1": {
    "sub_1": {
      "object_1": {
        "property_1": {},
        "property_2": {}
      }
    }
}
```

I want to import that JSON as a module and use nice autocompletion to select keys, but if I pass in
`section_1.sub_1.object_1` I want to have `"section_1.sub_1.object_1"` as an output.

Using `Object.keys()` is not the answer, because
`Object.keys(section_1.sub_1.object_1)` will give me `["property_1","property_2"]`

Example:

```
import paths from './paths.json'
...

<MyComponent data-path={jsonObjectNameFunction(section_1.sub_1.object_1)} />
...
```

I want `data-path="section_1.sub_1.object_1"`

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Can you please provide a specific example step by step? Where do you want the autocompletion to appear? Where is that string output from?

Comment: @Hawk Please, see my updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to pass in not just `section_1.sub_1.object_1` but also the object to look within (let's call it `obj`), like this;

```
const obj = /*the import resulting in:*/{
  "section_1": {
    "sub_1": {
      "object_1": {
        "property_1": {},
        "property_2": {}
      }
    }
};
someFunction(obj, obj.section_1.sub_1.object_1);
```

To implement `someFunction`, we have to find the name/value pairs at each level that lead go `obj`, something like this:

```
function someFunction(container, target, path = "") {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(container)) {
        const possiblePath = path ? path + "." + key : key;
        if (value === target) {
            return possiblePath;
        }
        if (value && typeof value === "object") {
            const found = someFunction(value, target, possiblePath);
            if (found) {
                return found;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
"use strict";

const obj = /*the import resulting in:*/{
    "section_1": {
        "sub_1": {
            "object_1": {
                "property_1": {},
                "property_2": {}
            }
        }
    }
};
console.log(someFunction(obj, obj.section_1.sub_1.object_1));

function someFunction(container, target, path = "") {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(container)) {
        const possiblePath = path ? path + "." + key : key;
        if (value === target) {
            return possiblePath;
        }
        if (value && typeof value === "object") {
            const found = someFunction(value, target, possiblePath);
            if (found) {
                return found;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I understand u want to get value from object base on path.

U can use lodash [get value by path](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get)

Comment: I think he wants the opposite. Get path based on value.